# VT enabled in BIOS but KVM failed to detect

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I Have Dell OPTIPLEX 755 machine with VT enabled in BIOS but when i trying to check using KVM i am getting following error

I am missing something?

```
root@nova-controller:~# kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS
HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
root@nova-controller:~#
```

## UPDATE:

```
root@nova-controller:~# sudo modprobe kvm_intel
FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel (/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko): Operation not supported
```

dmesg

```
[   57.887352] kvm: disable TXT in the BIOS or activate TXT before enabling KVM
[   57.887354] kvm: disabled by bios
[   61.199353] kvm: disable TXT in the BIOS or activate TXT before enabling KVM
[   61.199355] kvm: disabled by bios
[  965.566334] kvm: disable TXT in the BIOS or activate TXT before enabling KVM
[  965.566337] kvm: disabled by bios
```

Comment: What happens when you do the `sudo modprobe kvm_intel`. `dmesg` should show some messages.

Comment: Make sure you did what it said: physically power off the computer and power it back on.

Comment: @NathanC - I have updated question with command output

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I have shutdown box removed power cable for 1 min and reboot again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your BIOS [you should have](http://reidablog.blogspot.com/2008/06/with-correct-bios-settings-enabled-on.html) the following settings:

- Security: **Execute Disable** should be **On**
- Performance: **Virtualization** should be **On**
- Performance: **VT for Direct I/O Access** should be **On**
- Performance: **Trusted Execution** should be **Off**

After changing these and saving the settings, physically power off the computer and power it back on.

Comment: Holy Moly!! You guys are super awesome!!! `Trusted Execution should be Off` did magic!!

Comment: The same worked when VirtualBox reported that VT-x was disabled in the BIOS even though it was definitely enabled.

Comment: This is what worked for me on Dell Precision M2400. I can't stress enough how useful this answer is. Please everyone if you find this useful vote UP. I had very strange problems with networking (freezing on ssh connection) on using vagrant with virtualbox. This solved it for me. Thank you very much.